# Salesforce JavaScript OnClick Custom Button in Console

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

All -

I am trying to create a custom button for the Sales console. This button is calling a specific E-Mail Template and prepopulating data.

I know how to leverage the JavaScript for Custom Buttons that bring up web pages or links for the Salesforce Console, but when I try to combine that functionality with the JavaScript to auto select a template for e-mail I get the following error:

Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Here is my code......what am I missing here?

```
    srcUp('
         location.replace('
                /email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9/
         ');
    ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the following code in Javascript of your custom button,

FROM

srcUp('
         location.replace('
                      /email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9/
         ');
    ');

TO

location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9&p5=');

Note- No need to change the template id, I have changed the template id by the id provided by you in the code.

Let me know if this works, or if you need more help.

Ashish Shishodiya